# Socket.io emit message to certain sockets (architecture)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have an application where a user has a profile with a cork board.

When a user writes something on an others user profile everyone that is on that profile page should receive the emit.

On client side I connect to the socket server like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var socket = io.connect("https://10.94.30.134:8080");
    // ...
};
```

Note that that the client.js loads and connect on every access to my profile.html. I can't imagine that this is a good approach.

On server side I then use `rooms` to determine on which profile page the user currently is located.

```
sio.on("connection", function(socket){
    socket.join(socket.handshake.session.last_visited_profile);
    // ...
    socket.on("send-corkboard-message", function(data) { // ...
    socket.on("send-chat-message", function(data) { // ...  
});
```

The current approach works, but I think there is a lot to improve. I also got problems testing this set up with my mobile devices. They take about 5-10 seconds to connect to the socket server. (This is why I imagine storing the socket connection somewhere global on client side would be better.) If so, I don't have the opportunity to let the socket join rooms upon connection, I rather had to do this within my routes or client side with something like a subscribe event?

Is it a good approach to have all socket.io events (`"send-corkboard-message", "send-chat-message"`) *within* the `connection` event?

Maybe you can help or link me to some socket.io architecture that would improve my current situation. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't store the socket connection on the client side. The server is what maintains the connection, and also handles heartbeats and rooms. As for your second question, it isn't a matter of *if* the events should be within the `connection` handler, but rather that you *have* to put them within that handler.

For example, if we have a handler:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.emit('event', data);
});
```

The `socket` object is online defined within the handler. Therefore, you can't attach events outside of it.

As for your architecture, you should avoid sending data to clients which don't need the data. Therefore, if you have entire groups of clients which do or don't need certain data, you can create rooms, and have a client subscribe to a certain room on connect:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('subscribe', function(room) {
    socket.join(room);
  });
  socket.on('unsubscribe', function(room) {
    socket.leave(room);
  });
});
```

Then on the client side:

```
var socket = io.connect('/');
socket.emit('subscribe', 'room1');
```

Also do note that you don't need to wait for the DOM to load in order to create a Socket.IO connection. So you don't need `window.onload = function() {};`, which may speed up the establishing of the connection.

Comment: Thank you! When I end up in the connection handler on every site request anyways, I may as well "subscribe" within the connection handler on the server, like I described in my post above?

Comment: Is that a question or statement?

Comment: I'd like to have your opinion on this, yes.

Comment: I don't really know how your application might be structured, but yeah, avoid sending data to clients that don't need them.